# An Séimhiú agus an tUrú

Tags: code-golf, natural-language

## An Séimhiú agus an tUrú

In Irish Gaelic (Gaeilge) there are a number of ways that the start of a word can be changed. The most common of these are lenition (an séimhiú) and eclipsis (an t-urú)

Lenition involves adding the letter *h* as the second letter. For example, the word "bean" (woman) would be lenited to "bhean".

Eclipsing adds a prefix to the word. The prefix is determined by the first letter of the word. For example, the word "capall" (horse) starts with a *c*. Its eclipsis is *g*. So when the word "capall" is eclipsed it becomes "gcapall".

### Challenge

Write a function or program that takes a word and returns both its lenited and eclipsed forms.

#### Lenition

Only words beginning with:

```
b
c
d
f
g
m
p
s
t
```

are lenited. Words beginning with other letters are not changed.

**Some examples:**

```
bean       bhean
capall     chapall
Sasana     Shasana
lón        lón
Ífreann    Ífreann
```

#### Eclipsis

If a word starts with any of the following letters, it is prefixed by its respective eclipsis:

```
Letter   Eclipsis
b        m
c        g
d        n
f        bh
g        n
p        b
t        d
```

Words that don't start with those letters remain unchanged.

**Examples:**

```
bean        mbean
capall      gcapall
cailín      gcailín
doras       ndoras
fuinneog    bhfuinneog
Gaeilge     nGaeilge
Sasana      Sasana
```

There are other changes that can happen to the start of a word, but we'll just focus on these ones.

### Rules

The input is only one word. Words will only contain `a-z`, `A-Z` or the *fada* vowels `á`, `Á`, `é`, `É`, `í`, `Í`, `ó`, `Ó`, `ú` and `Ú`.

To make it a bit more simple the word itself doesn't necessarily need to be an Irish word, just that it is treated like one in the code. So inputting `delta` should return `dhelta` and `ndelta`.

For this challenge you can assume that the input words have not already been lenited or eclipsed (in Irish, a word is only lenited or eclipsed once. You would never end up with "bhhean" or "ngcapall").

[Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422), including [the default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/). Similarly, [default loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).

Finally, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
Input      Lenited     Eclipsed
bean       bhean       mbean
capall     chapall     gcapall
fuinneog   fhuinneog   bhfuinneog
Sasana     Shasana     Sasana
Gaeilge    Ghaeilge    nGaeilge
lón        lón         lón
áthas      áthas       áthas
Ífreann    Ífreann     Ífreann
```

Comment: [Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17257/78954).

Comment: what does the title mean?

Comment: @Giuseppe I think it means _lenition and eclipsis_. Now, the special thing about Gaelic, is that it's hard to understand even once translated into English. :p

Comment: @Arnauld Google Translate gives "The Lenition and the Turu" for the first time and "The Sharing and the Substance" afterwards... "agus" translates to "and".

Comment: "(The) Lenition and (the) Eclipsis". I'm not a fluent speaker, so I don't know if it's correct to specify them with the definite article (_an_). _Séimhiú_ is lenition and _urú_ is eclipsis. In the title _Urú_ takes a 't' at the start, because it starts with a vowel and is preceded by the definite article. When it's a capital letter there's no hyphen between them. Hence: "There are other changes that can happen to the start of a word, but we'll just focus on these ones."

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>98</s>  97 bytes

Returns an array `[lenited, eclipsed]`.

```javascript
s=>[(x=[...'2n1111gbnd1m1','bh',2][parseInt(c=s[0],30)*17%22])>'1'?c+'h'+s.slice(1):s,x>{}?x+s:s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZA/boMwFIf3nsJL9aBQiOlQKRJkjDpnRAzGMTaVYxCmFVLVI/QQPUOPkINRjE0G522ffu/T@/NOPommQ9uPz6o7s7nJZ50XZTDlZZIkkCm8FK/VGV8wxFALiLOq7Mmg2ZsaA5rrclfFL7vwCb8@ZlkVFoDhQCMQEOlEy5ayAId7HU/F1/dhivReVzPtlO4kS2THgyaAmhEFaKkwRGmKarGwQZSii8kevH5KeiIlbP1UrLz2c5v5RvPRKsU6DtZohGNkpm2hL52IJorcxpzEyusYG/nCkbBWcgZOOArLRlAu8xV5/bOnO8cwQu54A75w/R2XPeAmWHaChTvlpxmWL6ptr42t4mD@Bw)

#### How?

We define the following lookup table:

```javascript
A = [ ...'2n1111gbnd1m1', 'bh', 2 ]

//     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13  14
A = [ '2', 'n', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'g', 'b', 'n', 'd', '1', 'm', '1', 'bh', 2 ]
```

where:

- a single character (or the string *"bh"*) is used for eclipsis; all letters that trigger eclipsis also trigger lenition
- \$1\$ means that there's no eclipsis and no lenition
- \$2\$ means that there's no eclipsis but there is lenition

The first letter of the input word is converted from Base30 to decimal, multiplied by \$17\$ and then reduced with a modulo \$22\$. The result is used to pick the correct value from \$A\$.

Any result above \$14\$ yields *undefined*, and so does any letter in the range **u-z** or any fada vowel. An undefined value is interpreted the same way as \$1\$ (no eclipsis, no lenition).

```
  1st letter | from Base30 | * 17 | mod 22 | A[n]
-------------+-------------+------+--------+-----------
      a      |      10     |  170 |   16   | undefined
      b      |      11     |  187 |   11   | 'm'
      c      |      12     |  204 |    6   | 'g'
      d      |      13     |  221 |    1   | 'n'
      e      |      14     |  238 |   18   | undefined
      f      |      15     |  255 |   13   | 'bh'
      g      |      16     |  272 |    8   | 'n'
      h      |      17     |  289 |    3   | '1'
      i      |      18     |  306 |   20   | undefined
      j      |      19     |  323 |   15   | undefined
      k      |      20     |  340 |   10   | '1'
      l      |      21     |  357 |    5   | '1'
      m      |      22     |  374 |    0   | '2'
      n      |      23     |  391 |   17   | undefined
      o      |      24     |  408 |   12   | '1'
      p      |      25     |  425 |    7   | 'b'
      q      |      26     |  442 |    2   | '1'
      r      |      27     |  459 |   19   | undefined
      s      |      28     |  476 |   14   | 2
      t      |      29     |  493 |    9   | 'd'
 u-z or fada |     NaN     |  NaN |  NaN   | undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>83</s> 77 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to Jo King*

```perl6
{S:i/^<[bcdfgmpst]>/$/h/,{S/0/bh/}({$_ x tr/dbcfptg/nmg0bd/}($= m/./.lc))~$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYwxCoMwFECv8odQFIrfqUNR1x7AsbTyE5MoJDEkFipib9BD9ACdegQPZp3e8B7Py2BOm53goKDc5vrc4724ctEqbX0cbxUy7PA415gj73BJZtbAE8aALRfKjxqd1Tlvd8NKsJhhZkSavlizbJEmUAlrUlBDgIJLciDIkzE7erN@HbRDoAjq0TsnBw01RXIEF5K90RLM@nOwfsZub9a3CvvAVdsf)

Returns a two-element list.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>45</s> 44 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.•1˜3WÓƵ•sнlk©diн'hI¦JI®7‹i.•B}в •S„bhš®èì]‚
```

Ended up longer than I anticipated beforehand.. Can probably be golfed some more, though.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDIsPTc4zDD08@thXILr6wNyf70MqUzAt71TM8Dy3z8jy0zvxRw85MkEKn2gubFIB08KOGeUkZRxceWnd4xeE1sY8aZv3/n1aamZeXmp8OAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVnl4gr2SwqO2SQpK9pVh//UeNSwyPD3HOPzw5GNbgeziC3tzsg@tTMm8sFc9I/LQMq/IQ@vMHzXszAQpdKq9sEkBSAc/apiXlHF04aF1h1ccXlN7eLVL7aOGWf91/ielJuZxJScWJObkcKWVZublpeancwUnFifmJXK5J6Zm5qSncuUc3pzHdXhhSUZiMdfh3rQioJY8AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.•1˜3WÓƵ•                   # Push compressed string "fbcdgptms"
s                           # Swap to take the (implicit) input-string
 н                          # Get its first character
  l                         # Convert it to lowercase
   k                        # Get the index in the string (-1 if not found)
    ©                       # Store it in the register (without popping)
     di                     # If the index is non-negative (>= 0):
       н                    #  Get the first character of the (implicit) input-string again
        'h                 '#  Push a "h"
          I                 #  Push the input
           ¦                #  And remove its first character
            J               #  Join all three strings together
       I                    #  Then push the input-string again
        ®7‹i                #  If the index from the register is smaller than 7:
            .•B}в •         #   Push compressed string "mgnnbd"
                   S        #   As a list of characters: ["m","g","n","n","b","d"]
                    „bhš    #   And prepend "bh" to this list: ["bh","m","g","n","n","b","d"]
                        ®è  #   Then use the index from the register in this list
                          ì #   And prepend it in front of the input-string
      ]                     # Close both if-statements
       ‚                    # Pair the two strings at the top of the stack
                            # (uses the input implicitly if we haven't entered the first if)
                            # (and output this pair of strings implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tips of mine (section *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•1˜3WÓƵ•` is `"fbcdgptms"` and `.•B}в •` is `"mgnnbd"`.

Alternative for `.•B}в •S„bhš` with the same byte-count can be `.•„Å'ÀāÊˆÑ•#`, where `.•„Å'ÀāÊˆÑ•` is the compressed string `"bh m g n n b d"` and `#` will split on spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 100 bytes

```python
lambda w,l='bBcCdDgGpPtTfF':(w[0]+'h'*(w[0]in'msMS'+l)+w[1:],[*'mgnnbd','bh',''][l.find(w[0])//2]+w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcu9DsIgFEDhV3G7UIj1Z2vSRU2dTEx0Q4YiQkngligN8aF8Ch8MTZeTbznxnYYRt8W0t@L7oHS/yNy3oHb3vT7YYzynq@mgIVmsJIMBqlkOIbxOF2CesizWjeSigmARlQYOavgHpPBL41DPA63rjWSZlvh0mIghDuOUCKW0dNP3g/gY7Q8)

-3 thanks to [Black Owl Kai](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81238/black-owl-kai).

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü≤↔y╩▓╤:ï{╪Θ↨ë24¿→Äw↔t⌠íΘq↕:pWhg2╗P♦_}éBb
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81f31d79cab2d13a8b7bd8e917893234a81a8e771d74f4a1e971123a7057686732bb50045f7d824262&i=bean%0Acapall%0Afuinneog%0ASasana%0AGaeilge%0Al%C3%B3n%0A%C3%A1thas%0A%C3%8Dfreann&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <strike>121</strike> <strike>122</strike> <strike>116</strike> 98 Bytes

-24 bytes thanks to @mazzy

```
param($a)$a-replace'^[bcdfgmpst]','$&h';@{b='m';c='g';d='n';g='n';f='bh';p='b';t='d'}[''+$a[0]]+$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrLCsIwEEbhlwn@ihXcDwN9j5DC5NJ0kdQhLbgQnz0GN@fbHH29Uzu2VErvKk3q1cjNyKMlLRISFutDXHPV43SYYC4baP54RgUFRgZFxg7K/64MPwYdgE5GxNcCdyP26dyg9x8)

Uses a simple regex for the lenition and a <strike>switch statement</strike> far superior hashtable thanks to @mazzy for the eclipsis. This can probably get a lot shorter.

Comment: maybe you should think about: 1) replace a first letter only, 2) switch as expression `$(switch -r($a[0]){'b'{'m'}'c'{'g'}....})+$a`, 3) hashtable instead the switch.

Comment: Thanks, @mazzy, but I'm not sure how to use a hashtable in this situation. Could you give me an idea of what this might look like?

Comment: `param($a)$a-replace'^[bcdfgmpst]','$&h';@{b='m';c='g';d='n';g='n';f='bh';p='b';t='d'}[''+$a[0]]+$a`

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 151 bytes

```cs
x=>{var p=(char)(x[0]%32+96);return(x.Insert(1,(a+"ms").Contains(p)?"h":""),p==102?"bh"+x:"mgnnbd "[a.IndexOf(p)<0?6:a.IndexOf(p)]+x);};var a="bcdgpt";
```

It's really long, and there are probably ways to golf it more. But I'm just too lazy.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5Ni8IwFEX38yvKg4EX2pGqUJjG2MWAMivdSxevSfoBGksSJSDz22PFgXFWFw73co90H9INcXMxcuW8HUyX4W8@g62TNhExiPXtSjYZBcqeLMNwyOv35SL9LBi32l@swTD7Nk5bj/MMKYWTAzb7OhtPg3E4sgp6KAFYNgoxzxcVND2koYRTZ0yjEjjQtFc67NqpvMqronwFdRoY/@EPBxLQSNWNHnjcT44eWwR1tjQdMv72h/TR03@07UkfB9XpB453)

Comment: Your answer only covers lowercase inputs, so `Gaeilge` is for example incorrect. PS: Since you only use `b` once, you can golf `string a="bcdgpt",b="mgnnbd ";` to `var a="bcdgpt";` and `b[` to `"mgnnbd "[`.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen Fixed

Comment: Nice, +1 from me. Two small things to golf: put the `var a="bcdgpt";` inside the method, because you don't have to count the trailing semi-colon of lambda functions. And you can change the `%32+96` to `|32` to convert to lowercase. [Try it online **147 bytes**](https://tio.run/##VY4/C8IwFMR3P0V50wutpSo4tE07CIqT7uLwmqR/QGNJogTUz14rOuh03I877oSdCtsN66sWuXWm002EX/0IK4I64IPnxf1GJiAOlZBN7yB7256jaMkw9Ifk@FjMWWaUuxqNPt5qq4zDWYQUwtkCi1cX7ajTFntWQgspAIt6zmfJvISqhdCncG60rmQABxr7UvldPYbzpFymv@AYepY9h2yyHx86rBHkxdA4wX6ROjn6R5uW1KmTjXrj4QU)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that last string.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>140</s> 135 bytes

```java
s->{var h=s.charAt(0);int i="fbcdgptms".indexOf(h|32);return(i<0?s:h+"h"+s.substring(1))+" "+",bh,m,g,n,n,b,d,,".split(",",10)[i+1]+s;}
```

Port of [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178529/52210).
-5 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZBBTsMwEEX3PcXIK1txoxZ2hIJYsaIsuqy6mDhO7OK4UcapQCVH4BCcgSP0YMGtwhJFlkb2@Gn8n/d4xPm@eBuUQyJ4QetPMwDrg25LVBrWlyPAJrTWV6D4uCGRxX4/i4UCBqtgDR5WMND84XTEFsyKUmWwfQp8IbI4D@yKlbkqqibUxFLrC/3@WnLzeXsjslaHrvXc3i8e6c4kzLCEUupyur7Gl0IkDFjCZG5kLSvp48plISVLqXE2cCaZXC7E1ibLXUJZP2SXaE2XuxhtTHg82ALqaDhKbHeAYtT7oKDr9NCFtIlXwXnuU8VZrtEzcXX9H1LYoHOTWNlZ7/WhmgQ3SOhxEntGbV2lJzl3/pl2OH8HgzSNfZVt/JK/ef2sH34B)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                              // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  var h=s.charAt(0);              //  Get the first character of the input
  int i="fbcdgptms".indexOf(h     //  Get its index in the string "fbcdgptms"
                            |32); //  After converting it to lowercase
  return(i<0?                     //  If the index is -1 (not found):
          s                       //   Return the input unchanged
         :                        //  Else:
          h                       //   Return the first character
          +"h"                    //   Appended with an "h"
          +s.substring(1))        //   Appended with the rest of the string
         +" "                     //  Then append a space delimiter
         +",bh,m,g,n,n,b,d,,".split(",",10)
                                  //  Push {"","bh","m","g","n","n","b","d","",""}
          [i+1]                   //  and append the character at index `i+1`
         +s;}                     //  And append the input-string
```

Comment: [135 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZCxTsMwEIb3PsXJk61Qq4WNUBATE2XoWHW4OE7s4riRz6lAJY/AQ/AMPEIfLLgojCiDLdv36e7/vMcjzvfl66AcEsEzWn@aAVgfdahQaVhfrgCbGKyvQfHxQCJP7/0sbRQxWgVr8LCCgeb3pyMGMCuSymB4jHwh8tQP7IpVhSrrNjbEpPWlfnupuPm4uRZ50LELntu7xQPdmowZlpGkrqDfaXwpRMaApVUYaKBOozwUUAIwSa2zkafq1XIhtjZb7jLK@yG/RGu7wqVoY8LjwZbQJMNRYrsDFKPeO0XdyEMXZZtK0XnupeKs0OiZ@HX9H1LYonOTWNVZ7/WhngQ3SOhxEntCbV2tJzl3/p52OH9FgzSNfVYhfclfv37WDz8): `s->{var h=s.charAt(0);int i="fbcdgptms".indexOf(h|32);return(i<0?s:h+"h"+s.substring(1))+" "+" bh m g n n b d  ".split(" ",10)[i+1]+s;}`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, smart use of `",bh,m,g,n,n,b,d,,".split(",",10)[i+1]` (I've changed the spaces to commas, since it's a bit more readable)! Would have never thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>165</s>, <s>131</s>, 126 bytes

Edit:  ASCII-only with -34 bytes.  Puts everything into one string.

Edit2:  Kevin Cruijssen with the 5 byte golf to ToUpper()!

```cs
p=>{var s="BCDFGMPSTMGN N B D";var k=s.IndexOf(p.ToUpper()[0]);return(p.Insert(1,k<0?"":"h"),k<0?p:s[k]==70?"bh"+p:s[k+9]+p);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDPasJAEMbveYphT7vYBnsqNcaCiiJUK2jpQTxM4iYurptlZyMt4iP0IfoMfQQfLI1Krw1zmD/fjw@@Sek@LZysSlImh8UnebmPglQjEcxdkTvcHwMAWyZapUAefd0OhdrAFJXh4iICjEqTdsm72uMO@N9w66IHCcSVjXvHAzqgmPUHw9F4Ol8sp@MZzKAPQxZdpF1M4cRs5Mdrxm24LN6slY6LVXstIid96Ux9nhiSzvOHu123/cxYh22ZuM62Q6vdOo4f63OyZa3r3npat6yITlUU3LKFg8JQoWX47pSXL8pInnCWSDRMiP@hFC1q3YhlpTJGFnkjuEBCg43YGKXSuWzk9PmnOcP522@RmrGvzNUvufkFp7qqOtZGE@oMfwE)

Comment: [131](https://tio.run/##hZDBasJAEIbveYphT7toQz3ZmkZBRSlUK2jpQTxM4iYurptlZyMt4iP0IfoMfQQfzEZCrw1zmPlnPn74J6W7tHDyWpIyOSw/yctDFKQaiWDhitzh4RQA2DLRKgXy6Kt2LNQWZqgMF7cjwKQ06RN5V3m0gf8NdRd9SCC@2rh/OqIDitlwNJ5MZ4vlajadwxyGMGYtG66KN2ul4yK6YfuYwmezlR@vGad152EjIid96Qy31Z6k87zT3vc73QFjPbZjoha2R@v9Jo679wOW7Crbm249blpWROdrFNQBw1FhqNAyfHfKyxdlJE84SyQaJsT/UIoWtW7EslIZI4u8EVwiocFGbIpS6Vw2cvry05zh8u13SM3YV@aql9R@wbmqaxVrqwl1hr8)

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZDPasJAEMbveYphT7vYBnsqNcaCiiJUK2jpQTxM4iYurptlZyMt4iP0IfoMfQQfLI1Krw1zmD/fjw@@Sek@LZysSlImh8UnebmPglQjEcxdkTvcHwMAWyZapUAefd0OhdrAFJXh4iICjEqTdsm72uMO@N9w66IHCcSVjXvHAzqgmPUHw9F4Ol8sp@MZzKAPQxZdpF1M4cRs5Mdrxm24LN6slY6LVXstIid96Ux9nhiSzvOHu123/cxYh22ZuM62Q6vdOo4f63OyZa3r3npat6yITlUU3LKFg8JQoWX47pSXL8pInnCWSDRMiP@hFC1q3YhlpTJGFnkjuEBCg43YGKXSuWzk9PmnOcP522@RmrGvzNUvufkFp7qqOtZGE@oMfwE) Removed the `+p.ToUpper()` from the string `s`, so you can use `p.ToUpper()[0]` and `k<0` instead of `s[18]` and `k>17`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 101 bytes

```perl6
{.subst(/:i ^<[bcdfgmpst]>/,{$_~'h'}),.subst(/^./,{(%(<b m c g d n f bh g n p b t d>){.lc}//'')~$_})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BboMwFETX4RSjiBYsRdBusigEddcDdBkRZINNLJkPwrCILOcGPU2PkINRV2pX8/Q0I80kZ3PchhueFU6by@wq7JLmbxqX8izaTvXDZJe6yg8ubu7JNfHs8F@6ZMGmT2kpMKBFjw4EBXENSJggsKCrmMtM6/M8Sdg9bjzzWxGpcUYpJCe0fOLGhNBGE7px5hZq1URy7PHBpTa9xCe3nDjM45vw@FJzGFIFF@3C7/dhXXCCSuOGFdHO8hv2cQP3688vtf@j19rvi8hvPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 118 bytes

```python
s='fbcdgpt'
def f(w):a=w[0].lower();return w[0]+'h'*(a in'ms'+s)+w[1:],dict(zip(s,'bmgnnbd')).get(a,'')+'h'*(a=='f')+w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9NbsMgEEb3OQVSFwO1FbXqLpXXPUCWURZg8yfhMTJEqLlWjtCDuQY7pSOxmPe9mRH@O5oJP5YldKBEP2gf4TBIRRRN7MS7dHm7Ht2U5EzZ5yzjbUaSWQMGXiknFmEM0ATWpMv76doOto/0bj0NLYhRI4oBGDtqGSlvAdg@163X1iYtfrYYqaIgJMfVJKVe1ifMSraWjDk9/Lk999y53c5ubwoprt7SaqubRZSTLn62ldlJufKM68CZB4783/qzKaSs38Iqf3FpnZabneUdFBn3puru51G/WfxMyLNys/wC)

Comment: I'm afraid it returns the wrong elipses for 'bean', 'capall' and 'fuinneog'.

Comment: @Ciaran_McCarthy Fixed

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 77 bytes

```
i`^[bcdfgmpst]
$&h$'¶$&$&
T`L`l`¶.
¶f
¶ph
T`\ptcb\dgms`b\dgmnn_`¶.
^.+$
$&¶$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBDoIwEAXQ/ZyjookJ12DjTncizABtaVLGhtZjeAjPYNIDlIPVyuLnJz//rTIYpnw4NZgNdvdhnJRenA8PENUsjimKSlRwwwtaTLGGFFWJm8vUujAO7aQXj3sx9/ulq8@i6D/NeZDEMJIja0G9DLN8ariSJyZoSBqrJdjty7B9wkwetrdaC@Ef) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
i`^[bcdfgmpst]
$&h$'¶$&$&
```

If the word can be lenited, create the lenition, and make a copy for the eclipsis with a duplicate first letter.

```
T`L`l`¶.
```

Lowercase the duplicate letter.

```
¶f
¶ph
```

If it's an `f` then change it to `ph`; it will get fixed to `bh` later.

```
T`\ptcb\dgms`b\dgmnn_`¶.
```

Fix or remove the eclipsis (`m` and `s` have a lentition but no eclipsis).

```
^.+$
$&¶$&
```

If there was no lentition then duplicate the word anyway.

Answer (score 0):

#### **JAVASCRIPT 131 bytes**

Implementing Kevin Cruijssen answer in javaScript:

```
(w,i='bcdfgmpst'.indexOf(w.toLowerCase()[0]))=>(i>=0?[w,w[0]+'h'+w.substr(1),'m,g,n,bh,n,,b,,d'.split(',')[i]+w]:[w,w,w]).join(' ')
```

```
(
 w,                                                          // the input (string)
 i='bcdfgmpst'.indexOf(w.toLowerCase()[0])                   // the index of the lenited word
)=>(                                                         
i>=0?                                                        // if index greater or equals 0
 [w,w[0]+'h'+w.substr(1),'m,g,n,bh,n,,b,,d'.split(',')[i]+w] // return Array(input, lenited, eclipsis) 
:                                                            // else
 [w,w,w]                                                     // return Array(input, input, input)
).join(' ')                                                  //Join array items with spaces
```